# Prove a group is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $S = \mathbb{R} \space \backslash$ $\{-1\}$ and define a binary operation on $S$ by $a*b = a + b+ ab$. Prove that $(S,*)$ is an abelian group.

This is problem 7 in chapter 3 of Judson's Abstract Algebra book. I was trying to work on it and can't figure it out.

Comment: First prove $S$ is a group and then show that the operation is commutative. Which part of this are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 3):

The idea is that the set of all non-zero real numbers forms an abelian group under multiplication. The group in question is the same group except every number has been moved to the right by one unit on the real number line. So $-1$ is the new zero.

In other words, if you take non-zero $x$ and $y$ , and define the operation as $z = x\cdot y$. Substitute $x=1+a$, $y = 1+b$ and $z = 1+c$, then
$$1+c = (1+a)(1+b) = 1+a+b+ab \implies c = a+b+ab =: a*b.$$

Armed with this idea, I hope you will find it easy to prove $S$ is a group.

---

Edit: (answering the comments below)

1. $a*0 = a$. So $0$ is the identity element of the group.
2. Show that $\left(\frac1{a+1} - 1\right)$ is the inverse of $a$. Now you see why $a=-1$ is not allowed.

Now consider the map $\phi: S \to \mathbb{R}\backslash \{0\}$  given by $\phi(a) = a+1$. My answer above claims $\phi$ is a group isomorphism.

Comment: My only problem with this now is how to use that idea in the proof. More specifically, how do I express this idea in a formal manner? I don't think I could just say "-1 is the new zero" or that we shifted every element in the group $(\mathbb{R}\backslash\{0\},\cdot)$ but then again I'm not sure.

Comment: I have edited my answer and added more comments. You still have to work out the inverse, but I hope the details are enough to help you.

Answer (score 1):

First show $S$ is a group. The fact that $-1 \notin S$ is necessary for this to be true. Once you have shown it is a group, here is how you show it is abelian. Let $a,b \in S$. Then $$a \star b=a+b(1+a)\\ =a+b+ab \\=b+a(1+b) \\ =b\star a$$ So $S$ is abelian.

Comment: Alternatively, note that the formula on the right-hand-side is symmetric in $a, b$, and so it also is on the left-hand side.

Answer (score 1):

Let $a,b \in S$. Then $$a \star b=a+b+ab\\ =b+a+ba \\ =b\star a$$ So $S$ is abelian.

Look actually the map ($x \mapsto (x+1) )$  from  $\mathbb{R} \space \backslash$ $\{-1\}$ to $\mathbb{R} \space \backslash$ $\{0\}$ is a automorphism. So as $\mathbb{R} \space \backslash$ $\{0\}$ is abelian, so is $\mathbb{R} \space \backslash$ $\{-1\}$.

Comment: Here in \mathbb{R} \space \backslash$ $\{0\}$. The operation is usual multiplication.